# Electric field inside human body

Tags: electrical-engineering

Electric field inside a metal is zero , when it is placed in an external electric field. What about human body? If it is placed in an external electric field, will the field inside the body be zero? I am confused because human body is a conductor but not as good as metals.

Answer (score 2):

No. Humans are not faraday cages. This is the reason such things as MRI scanners work.

Comment: or neural networks.

Comment: To be fair, the skin depth of humans is highly frequency-dependent.